# Laravel: local and protuction time mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using same code local and production environment.
The code creates timestamp field in `password_resets` table (Laravel native password change)
On the local environment password changes correctly but on production server there is a 'code expired' error.
Checked both: server and mysql time but didn't found any solution.

Just fount differences in php settings:
On the local env:

```
date

date/time support => enabled
timelib version => 2018.01RC3
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2019.1
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Europe/Moscow

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => Europe/Moscow => Europe/Moscow
```

on prod server:

```
date

date/time support => enabled
timelib version => 2017.09
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Europe/Moscow

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => Europe/Moscow => Europe/Moscow
```

Comment: is your `timezone` entry on `config > app` is correct on the production?

Comment: it's `Europe/Moscow`. And server's `date +"%Z"` is `MSK`

Comment: You need to set your timezone in the `config` as @kapitan suggested.

Comment: So it's already set up as i commented below

Answer (score 0):

you can save time manually to the table. i face this issue

```
'created_at'=>date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
```